# Characters with good synergy in ME3 Multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Yesterday I happened to play with my N7 Fury and one of my teammates had his Drell Adept, with both characters at, or close to L20. I have to say that the game had never been this fun! :)

Those two characters are amazing together, benefiting from a fantastic synergy. Both fast and agile, packed with biotic powers triggering not only their own also each others biotic explosions. We practically destroyed collectors, as a team, and the two adepts were more often than not the saviors of the team. Even praetorians, or packs of possessed scions were relatively easy to sick given some wiggle room on the field.

Now I wonder what other characters have such good synergy. Which team compositions are as deadly, considering there are not only biotic explosion but also tech bursts, fire explosions etc etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reave and Warp make an awesome biotic combination. Both detonate each other and casting animation is fast.

Pick one character with Reave & one with Warp and you'll be detonating each others powers every 2-3 seconds.

That being said, the maximum biotic explosion damage comes from Warp+Throw & Warp+Shockwave combinations (sources below). Throw is arguably the best detonator power as it has a very fast recharge and detonates on all types of (what's the word for this? protection?) i.e. health/shield/barrier/armor.

So if the team has more than 2 players, equip one person with Throw and others with Warp/Reave/Dark Channel. Now the person with Throw has only one thing to do - spam the key that throws Throw, detonating every enemy in front of the team. (This is team-work, the team will need to stick together).

If there are only two biotics in the team, I'd suggest to go with Warp+Reave combination which is more reliable as Throw can only detonate and not initiate a biotic explosion.

**Maximising biotic damage**

Biotic explosion damage depends only on the ranks of the power and on nothing else not even from power damage bonuses (through some powers can be modified for extra combo damage, see source below). So ensure that the powers that you are using for biotic explosion are on Rank 6.

PS: Equip yourself with Acolyte, for the only place where biotics fall a little short - shields.

Sources:

1. [Mass Effect Wikia: Power Combos](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Combos)
2. [Bioware Social Netowork: Gameplay Data & Mechanics](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/9822648#9823097)
3. [Bioware Social Network: Combo Damage Calculation](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/14041340)
4. [Google Spreadsheet: Combo Damages](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AplMRQNEVa05dER4LUJlNHVYbXpzSDdzTjdMb0pTNnc)
5. [Mass Effect Wikia: Acolyte](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Acolyte)

Comment: Interesting... Thanks a lot for the links, although the spreadsheet contain only a few of the possible combinations. On a side note, what makes Fury + Drell so sweet is that they both have AoE powers that can set up, and relatively fast detonators. Knowing that my buddy is behind me, I practically go amok through the enemy with the Ann.Field on and just spam Throw while the Drell spam Reave as fast as he can.

Comment: @posdef No, the spreadsheet lists damages for all possible combinations. The first column `BE (no bonus)` is what applies to _Dark Channel + Reave_ combo. However, the powers that can be modified for extra combo damages like _Warp_, _Throw_ & _Shockwave_ are listed separately. For example the second column is what the damage would be if any Rank 6 biotic power is detonated with _Throw_. Read the forum post "Combo Damage Calculation" (link above) for more information.

Comment: Also to note that even though _Reave_ and _Dark Channel_ both are AoE powers, the combo will be detonated on only one enemy even if multiple are hit. Exception to this are _Cluster Grenades_ where all shrapnel can potentially detonate separate combos.

Comment: Not to be picky but imho the real combo for Fury is the one setup by Annihilation Field not Dark Channel. The reason behind that statement is the fact that AF once fired is almost a passive ability, with damage and staggering effect. So AF + Run like the wind + spam Throw = WIN :)

Answer (score 5):

N7 Destroyer + N7 Demolisher.

Where Destroyer is specced for Devastator Mode & Multi Frag Grenade, while Demolisher's Supply Pylon is maximised for ammo & grenade production, thus ensuring that ammo supply to Destroyer's Harrier & grenades never ends.

Add third player as Volus Engineer to the team with his Shield Boost maxed for restoring allies' shield and the Destroyer is an unstoppable juggernaut.

Add fourth player as Asari Justicar to the team with her Biotic Sphere maxed for protection and the Destroyer is [someone should edit the post and fill something clever here].

**Important note**: Since all characters are mostly in support role for the Destroyer. The Destroyer needs to ensure that he is maximised for Damage per Second (DPS) by using Ammo/Weapon/Armor consumables & Gear along with good weapons and appropriate weapon mods.

PS: Two N7 Destroyers with two support characters (with at least one of them being N7 Demolisher and another being a Volus Engineer or N7 Demolisher) will wreck havoc to the battlefield.

Answer (score 2):

You've already covered many biotic combinations, here are a couple of tech ones that might be of interest to anyone who happens upon this question:

(1) Snap freeze (N7 Paladin or AIU) and any character with chain overload (Human eng, Turian sentinel, Turian Ghost, Geth eng). Snap freeze works through walls and primes everything for 2x damage cryo explosions.

(2) Any character with flamer and any character with chain overload. Flamer will prime multiple enemies for fire explosions which do great damage against armour. In addition setting off fire explosions on bosses can sometimes help to take out lesser units in proximity.

Why is overload such a great detonator? It's hitscan and with one or both of the chain evolutions you can get multiple explosions per cast. In addition the overload damage is applied before the combo damage and as it's so effective at removing shields or barriers the combo damage will often hit enemy health/armour.

Here's a good video about combo explosions:

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Lash or Reave power bonus, one of the easy ways to chain a combo series is the Engineer first. Take Ida and Liara. The first big series is Overload -> Incinerate ->  Warp -> Lash/Reave. In this one, you chain the Tech/Fire/Biotic combo in a single series. Generally speaking, you can chain combo's starting from Tech followed by Fire, or Fire followed by Tech, and finish them with a Biotic detonation. The maximum detonation of a combo series is 3 (Fire Detonate Tech, or Tech Detonate Fire, and finally detonated by a biotic detonator power).

Another way is to use double detonation, because a Tech or Fire source stacks over a Biotic source. To use double detonation, you must have the Double Throw biotic power. In this case, the order is Warp -> Tech, or Warp -> Fire, followed by a Double Throw. The first throw detonates the stacked Fire or Tech, and the second throw detonates the Warp. Normally, in insanity, a double detonation Tech source based combo can remove the entire shield of a Banshee, and one or two of his armor segments. However, this is not the fastest way to kill a Banshee. You have other solutions to ensure a fast unpop of a banshee, because after you removed the shield, the Banshee starts parrying your powers. With the Engineer, you can unpop the Banshee before it start parrying. But this is another combination of powers using the Engineer.

Comment: Can you please signify or expand on what you mean by "the engineer first", "take Ida and Liara", and "unpop"?